# mysql error: Unknown column 'thread.threadid' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, vbulletin, mysql-error-1054

I'm getting the following error...

```
ERROR:
mysql error: Unknown column 'thread.threadid' in 'on clause'
```

I hear it has something to do with the MySQL version... what changes do I need to make to my PHP code to get passed this error?   I read that This error arises because the comma operator was used in the SELECT query. This query was not designed to work under the new MySQL 5 strict query parser, which treats commas as lower precedence than joins.

```
Database error in vBulletin 3.0.7:

Invalid SQL: 
    SELECT thread.threadid, thread.forumid
    FROM thread AS thread, subscribethread AS subscribethread
    LEFT JOIN deletionlog AS deletionlog ON(deletionlog.primaryid = thread.threadid AND type = 'thread')
    WHERE subscribethread.threadid = thread.threadid
    AND subscribethread.userid = 1
    AND thread.visible = 1
    AND lastpost > 1277054898
    AND deletionlog.primaryid IS NULL

mysql error: Unknown column 'thread.threadid' in 'on clause'

mysql error number: 1054
```

Can I simply take out the comma in the SELECT thread.threadid, thread.forumid?

Please explain...

Comment: Can you verify that `thread` has a `threadid` column and it's spelled properly?

Answer (score 0):

You want to join `thread` with `deletionlog` but the query is trying to join `subscribethread` with `deletionlog`. Replace it with:

```
FROM subscribethread AS subscribethread, thread AS thread
LEFT JOIN deletionlog AS deletionlog ON(deletionlog.primaryid = thread.threadid AND type = 'thread')
```

Comment: Why does the placement of the comma change things?  Why swap the words after the FROM?

Comment: @Vsh3r Your code tries to select from the table `thread` and the table obtained by left-joining the `subscribedthread` and `deletionlog` tables; what you really want is to select from the table `subscribethread` and the table obtained by left-joining `thread` and `deletionlog` tables.